# How to randomize a jquery animation among several elements with same class

Tags: jquery, animation

I have 10 boxes with same class ".tile" and I've written a piece of jquery code which will be run when document's loaded :

HTML :

```
<li>
    <a class="tile" href="#dev">
        <div class="boximg"></div>
        <div class="boxttl">
            <span class="engttl">Develope Your Mobile</span>
            <span class="fattl">آموزش و توسعه موبایل</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

JQUERY :

```
function func2($this) {
    if ($(this).find('.engttl').length)
        $this = this;

    if ($($this).attr('_to_animate') != 'true')
        return;

    $($this).find('.engttl').delay(2000).animate({marginTop:"-23px"},1100,'easeOutExpo',function(){
        var $this2 = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $($this2).animate({marginTop:"0"},1100,'easeOutExpo',function(){
                setTimeout(function(){ func2($this); },1500);
            });
        },1500);
    });
}
$('.tile').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('_to_animate', 'true');
    func2(this);
});
```

it works fine how I expect, but how can I randomize the animation between each ".tile" ?
with my code, after document load, we see the animation for all ".tile"s in the same time, but I want to see the animation for each ".tile" separately in different time.
I appreciate if anybody knows how to do that ? ..

Comment: A possible solution would be to use each and random so you loop through each `.engttl` and delay it by a random time...

Comment: yes, switch out your `.delay(2000)` for `.delay(Math.random() * 2000 + 1000)`

Comment: @paul - That would delay all of the animations by the same time would it not?

Comment: I think it will calculate a new delay for each selected element

Comment: Perfect Paul, it works how I want, THANK YOU SO MUCH <3

Comment: Lol, you know, I thought that would simply generate a one off value and use that, rather than repeatedly generate a new value each iteration. Good stuff @Paul.

Comment: would you guys please explain me what are 2000 and 1000 ? and what can I put in 'Math.random()' parenthesis ?

Comment: the `2000` and `1000` values make a delay between 1000 and 3000 milliseconds in total. You do not need to use any parameter in the call to `random()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch out your `.delay(2000)` for `.delay(Math.random() * 2000 + 1000)`

the 2000 and 1000 values make a delay between 1000 and 3000 milliseconds in total. You do not need to use any parameter in the call to `random()`.

Comment: So if I increase the difference between first and second digit, I've expanded the random time range, right ?

Comment: Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 1 (for example 0.6534). This is multiplied by 2000 to give a number between 0 and 2000. Then 1000 is added, this gives a number between 1000 and 3000, which is used for the delay in milliseconds